# minimize time when updating table with left join

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-update

I have 2 tables like:

```
-table1: id_1, id_2, id_3, ref_id (id_1, id_2 is pk)
-table2: ref_id, id_4
```

I want id_3 field should be equal to table2's id_4(ref_id is the primary key)
table1 has about 6 million records and table2 has about 2700 records.

I wrote a sql like:

```
update table1
set id_3 = b.id_3
from table1 
left join table2 b on id_1= b.ref_id
```

By using SQL Server the query takes so much time like about 16 hr and still no response. How can I reduce the query time?

Comment: What columns do you have indexes on? Might be an option to drop some index(es) before updating huge amounts of indexed data, and then rebuild the index afterwards – if possible, of course (if you don’t need forced uniqueness of column values or something).

Comment: I do not think that this took so long, so there exist no indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it is indeed taking absurdly long, but the lack of indices could be the cause of that. Without indices the database basically has to walk through 2700 records for every single  record in your 6M records table.

So start by adding an index (assuming the primary key isn't an index) on `ref_id` and also add an index on `id_1`.

To make things easier to monitor (in terms of progress) simply loop through the 2700 records in table 2 and do an update per record (or per 10, 100, etc..) so you can update in parts and see how far it gets.

Also, to make sure you don't do anything useless, I would recommend adding a `and table1.id_3 <> table2.id_3`

Answer (score 0):

Updating every row in a 6-million row table is likely to be slow regardless.

One way to get a benchmark for the maximum speed of updating every row would be to just time the query:

```
update table1
set id_3 = 100
```

Also, do you need to update rows in table1 that have no matching row in table2? In that case, switching the left outer join to an inner join would greatly improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question we really need to know what the clustered indexes on the two tables are. I can make a suggestion for the clustered indexes to make this particular query fast, however, other factors should really be considered when choosing clustered indexes.

So with that in mind, see if these indexes help:

table1: UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX on (id_1, id_2) 
table2: UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX on (ref_id)

Basically make your PKs clustered if they are not already.

The other important thing is whether the tables are seeing other traffic while you are running this update. If so, the long runtime may be due to blocking. In this case you should consider batching, i.e. updating only a small portion at a time instead of all in single statement.